# Why does FieldDoesNotExist not work on POST.get()?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to catch an exception if the form POST does not contain a value for the field 'myfield':

```
    try:
        set_var = request.POST.get('myfield')
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        raise FieldDoesNotExist("Your field is not here.")
```

Why does this not raise an exception?

Comment: Because `.get(..)` does a fallback to `None` if it does not exists. You likely want to subscript, with `request.POST['myfield']`.

Comment: Is there an exception to catch a fallback to None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`.get(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get) will in case the key does not exist, return the value you passed to the `default=…` parameter, and in case you did not pass a value for `default=…` yourself, `default` is `None`.

You probably want to *subscript* the `request.POST`, then you can catch the `MultiValueDictKeyError` exception:

```
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError

try:
    set_var = request.POST['myfield']
except MultiValueDictKeyError:
    raise FieldDoesNotExist('Your field is not here.')
```

Comment: Thanks, why does `.get` raise an `ObjectDoesNotExist` error if used on an object but not on a POST?

Comment: @alias51: these two methods have not much in common (except for the name). The "semantics" of the two are (completely) different.

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct that in using try/except, you should always except an error and raise an exception? Errors can be different from exceptions because exception types are just used for logging?

Comment: @alias51: you do not per se need to raise an error. You can try to "fix" the problem. For example set `set_var = 'other-value'`, etc. Exception types are mainly used to pass data about the exception, and to disambiguate in the `except` clauses.